# running several CMD files within one batchfile

Tags: batch-file

I would like to make a generic script that runs every CMD-file on several subfolders. E.g.

Each subfolder contains 1 CMD file (name is not the same). It's not the same subfolders each time
c:\folder\Folder1
c:\folder\folder2
c:\folder\folder3
etc

So I would like to search all subfolders and run all CMD-files on each subfolder.

Answer (score 1):

This is designed to:

1) look for every .bat file in a tree
2) change to each directory with a batch file, in turn
3) run the .bat file in the folder it is in

```
@echo off
for /r %%a in (*.bat) do (
   pushd "%%~dpa"
      call "%%a"
   popd
)
```

If you want to run every .bat file in the tree on every folder:

```
@echo off
for /r %%a in (*.bat) do (
 for /d /r %%b in (*) do (
  pushd "%%b"
      call "%%a"
  popd
 )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f %%a in ('dir /s /b *.cmd') do call %%a
```

`dir /s /b *.bat` builds a list of all cmd files

To run all those files in parallel, replace `call` with `start`